List containers in the Azure Data Lake Storage
I'm trying to list the containers inside a specific directory within Azure Data Lake Storage account, but it doesn't seem to be any function that can handle this:
Here is my hierarchy:
assets
 root
  container1
  container2
  container3
  container4
  container5

I wrote the following function that gets the path, and it shows all of the containers even inside the containerX. What I want to achieve is to just put the name of the containers in assets/root without having other containers deeper than containerX.
import os
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeServiceClient

connection_string = os.getenv("AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING")
data_lake_service_client = DataLakeServiceClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=connection_string)

filesystem_client = data_lake_service_client.get_file_system_client(file_system="assets")

paths = filesystem_client.get_paths(path="root")

for path in paths:
    if path.is_directory:
        print("\t" + path.name)

Its quite strange that there is no functions like

get_containers(path="")
or
list_containers(path="")

to just list them

Do you want to list the containers or directories can you give clarification?

@Bhavani containers are equivalent to directories in Azure Data Lake Storage

Please change the following line of code:
paths = filesystem_client.get_paths(path="root")

to
paths = filesystem_client.get_paths(path="root", recursive=False)

Based on the documentation available here, default value of recursive parameter is True and that's why you are seeing subfolders as well.

Do you know if there any  list_containers(path="") type of functions as this way with get_paths() function, it needs extra processing. I need to process the string and get the containers inside a list to be used later in my app.
Also when I try to write the function this way filesystem_client = data_lake_service_client.get_file_system_client(file_system="assets/root") , I get error. It doesn't mention in the documentation how to define nested containers inside file_system arg

Do you know if there any  list_containers(path="") type of functions as this way with get_paths() function, it needs extra processing. I need to process the string and get the containers inside a list to be used later in my app. - Take a look at azure/storage-blob package. You should be able to list folders there.

Also when I try to write the function this way filesystem_client = data_lake_service_client.get_file_system_client(file_system="assets/root") , I get error. It doesn't mention in the documentation how to define nested containers inside file_system arg - Instead of defining the subpath inside get_file_system_client, please define it in get_paths. I think that should work.
